# ¿Como eliminar un objeto de un array, según el valor de una propiedad, javascript?

Tags: javascript, array

tengo el array de la siguiente forma:

```
productos_seleccionados.push({
"codigo": codinv_material,
"precio": preciosocio_material
})
```

lo lleno apartir de unos valores tomados de unos inputs, generando un resultado de esta forma:

```
{codigo: "30909", precio: "48.3"}
{codigo: "30399", precio: "332.5"}
{codigo: "31541", precio: "269.5"}
```

como podría hacer para eliminar espeficamente el objeto con valor 30399 de la propiedad codigo
ya que despues debo ir eliminando los objetos segun el codigo que yo mande.
Por ejemplo si mando el codigo: 31541, debe eliminarse el objeto

```
{codigo: "31541", precio: "269.5"}
```

y asi enviando los valores dinamicamente.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function deleteItem(list, removeItem){
    arr = $.grep(list, function(item) {
      return item.codigo != removeItem;
    });
    return arr
}

new_list = deleteItem(productos_seleccionados, "31541");
console.log(new_list);
```

puedes recorrer toda la lista para comprobar que elemento es el que contiene el valor que quieres eliminar

Actualizar item:

```
function updateItem(list, updItem, new_value){
    arr = $.grep(list, function(item) {

        if(item.codigo == updItem ){
           return item.cantidad = new_value;
           // return item.cantidad = item.cantidad + 1;
        }else{
           return item;
        }
    });
    return arr
}
```

la linea comentada es una opción si la cantidad siempre va de uno en uno.

Comment: Gracias, perdona la molestia y como podria ir actualizar el valor de una propiedad segun el valor que envié: por ejemplo:
{codigo: "31541", precio: "269.5",  cantidad: 1}, pero cuando yo vuelva a seleccionar el producto, es decir aumentar de cantidad que voy a elegir, la propiedad cantidad vaya aumentando.
{codigo: "31541", precio: "269.5",  cantidad: 2} y asi sucesivamente.

Comment: te he actualizado mi respuesta, si tienes preguntas adiciones crea una pregunta nueva